# Tokenizer doesn't work properly in torchtext

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, spacy, torchtext

I got a problem in torchtext, and was struggling with it for a long time. I was trying to tokenize and numericalize the text using torchtext and spacy. I defined my tokenizer as this:

```
def Sp_Tokenizer(text): 
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_en.tokenizer(text)]
```

It worked good:

```
Sp_Tokenizer('How are you today')

['How', 'are', 'you', 'today']
```

Then I passed this tokenizer into torchtext:

```
TEXT = data.Field(sequential=True, tokenize=Sp_Tokenizer, lower=False)
```

and built the vocab:

```
corps = ['How are you', 'I am good today', 'He is not well']
TEXT.build_vocab(corps, vectors="glove.6B.100d")
```

Then I tried

```
TEXT.numericalize('How are you today')
```

I assumed I should get a tensor with 4 numbers (word level), however, what I got was like char level:

```
tensor([[ 6,  3, 10,  2,  4, 17,  5,  2, 11,  3, 19,  2,  9,  3,  7,  4, 11]])
```

What's wrong with that? Is there anythin I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs [here](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#torchtext.data.Field.numericalize) numericalize accepts pre-tokenized input, so you can't just pass it a string. You want either this for a single example:

```
TEXT.preprocess("Hello, how are you today?")
```

or this for a batch:

```
TEXT.process(["Hello, how are you today?"])
```